How to define a question that will attract "useful" answers?
After some time of programming in Python, I have learned that many tasks, which previously I performed in several lines, could be solved in a much more succinct way by one-liners, e.g. these ones. Other languages, too, have such idioms, which make their code both shorter and clearer (to those who know them).
I would like to present challenges that will attract answers that are both short and clear, such that they can be actually used in real code. But currently, the "code golf" challenge relies just on counting the number of characters, which often leads to very unclear and non-useful code.
How can I design my question such that it attracts answers that are short, but also clear and useful for real code?

You can ask in chat, I'm sure people would be willing to help out there.

This may not be something that is necessarily suitable for this site.
Not all of our challenges are code golf, as implied by the coding challenges part of our site name, but they are nonetheless all coding challenges, and part of that is the requirement for each challenge to have a clearly defined and objective scoring / winning criterion, whether that's shortest code in bytes, fastest code, asymptotically fastest algorithm, or any of the various other systems.
Unfortunately, "clear and readable" and "practically useful" are both unobservable requirements / metrics, meaning you cannot define what that means or objectively score or rank submissions on that basis.
You can encourage people to provide solutions that are clear but ultimately your challenge needs to be scored on an objective criterion and anything else is just additional stuff you can add in so long as your scoring itself remains objective and well-defined.

Is it acceptable in this site to limit answers only to "real" languages?

@ErelSegal-Halevi Yes. Firstly, you can't define what counts as real, and also refer to this meta consensus.
